# Loading the endpoint configuration from the system environment

Tags: environment-variables, elixir, runtime, config, phoenix-framework

I have the following endpoint initialization in `lib/flashcards_web/endpoint.ex`:

```erlang
  @doc """
  Callback invoked for dynamically configuring the endpoint.

  It receives the endpoint configuration and checks if
  configuration should be loaded from the system environment.
  """
  def init(_key, config) do
    if config[:load_from_system_env] do
      port = System.get_env("PORT") || raise "expected the PORT environment variable to be set"                                                      
      jwt_token_ttl_minutes =
        "USER_SESSION_MINUTES"
        |> System.get_env
        |> String.to_integer
      || raise "expected the USER_SESSION_MINUTES environment variable to be set"                                                                    

      config =
        config
        |> Keyword.put(:http, [:inet6, port: port])
        |> Keyword.put(:jwt_token_ttl_minutes, jwt_token_ttl_minutes)

      {:ok, config}
    else
      {:ok, config}
    end
  end
```

and the required `load_from_system_env: true` line in `config/dev.exs`:

```erlang
# For development, we disable any cache and enable
# debugging and code reloading.
#
# The watchers configuration can be used to run external
# watchers to your application. For example, we use it
# with brunch.io to recompile .js and .css sources.
config :flashcards, FlashcardsWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]],
  load_from_system_env: true
```

However when running

```sh
PORT=4000 USER_SESSION_MINUTES=1 iex -S mix phx.server
```

I get:

```erlang
iex(1)> Application.get_env(:flashcards, FlashcardsWeb.Endpoint)[:jwt_token_ttl_minutes]
nil
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try to `IO.inspect/2` the whole `Application.get_all_env/1`.

Comment: I tried looking at `Application.get_all_env(:flashcards)` initially - can't see the parameter in question anywhere there.

Comment: Is `config[:load_from_system_env]` indeed `true`?

Comment: It's set as such in `config/dev.exs`. I'm wondering if I'm looking in the right place - maybe the config is copied to an endpoint process and modified there.

Comment: Would you mind to put `IO.inspect("foo")` directly after `if config[:load_from_system_env] do` and check it enters there?

Comment: Sure, got `"foo"` in the `iex` prompt - also tried using `PORT=5000` and got `Running FlashcardsWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://:::5000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180744/discussion-between-category-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to access the dynamic endpoint configuration.

The docs mention that a [`config/2` function is automatically generated at the endpoint](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-endpoint-api).

The dynamic endpoint configuration can therefore be accessed as follows:

```
iex(2)> FlashcardsWeb.Endpoint.config(:jwt_token_ttl_minutes)
1
```